# Tikz: Reposition Legend (\node) next to Drawing (\draw)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make the "Legend" appear on the right hand side of the drawing...Any suggestions? I tried playing around with the anchoring direction and slope to no avail.

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/9,3.2/1/10,2/1.5/8,1.5/2/6, 2.5/2/7,1.2/2.5/2,2/2.5/4,3.1/2.5/5,2/3/1,2.9/2.9/3}{
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,label={[xshift=-3pt,yshift=2pt,scale=0.7]-60:$\mathrm{P}_{\z}$}] (\z) at (\x,\y){};
        }
        \node[draw,rectangle,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[draw,rectangle,top color=white,bottom color=gray!60,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (B) at (1.3,5) {};
        \draw (A.north west) -- (B.north west)
              (A.north east) -- (B.north east)
              (A.south west) -- (B.south west)
              (A.south east) -- (B.south east);
        \node (U) at (-1,5) {$\mathrm{U}_1$};
        \node at (-1,2) {$\mathrm{U}_2$};
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend left] (1.west);
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend right] (2.south);
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-1) {Legend:};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-1.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ - instantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ - uninstantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-2.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ - thin particulars};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-3) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ - bare particulars};
        \node[anchor=center,above = 0.1cm of B.north west,font=\bfseries\large] {Space-time manifold}; 

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

You don't need to place every label component but use only one node with all legend inside. If you fix some node's `text width` TiKZ will break lines accordingly, but you can also use `\\` to break them.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/9,3.2/1/10,2/1.5/8,1.5/2/6, 2.5/2/7,1.2/2.5/2,2/2.5/4,3.1/2.5/5,2/3/1,2.9/2.9/3}{
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,label={[xshift=-3pt,yshift=2pt,scale=0.7]-60:$\mathrm{P}_{\z}$}] (\z) at (\x,\y){};
        }
        \node[draw,rectangle,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[draw,rectangle,top color=white,bottom color=gray!60,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (B) at (1.3,5) {};
        \draw (A.north west) -- (B.north west)
              (A.north east) -- (B.north east)
              (A.south west) -- (B.south west)
              (A.south east) -- (B.south east);
        \node (U) at (-1,5) {$\mathrm{U}_1$};
        \node at (-1,2) {$\mathrm{U}_2$};
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend left] (1.west);
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend right] (2.south);
        \node[anchor=west, text width=5cm, right=1cm of B.east] {Legend:\\ {\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ - instantiated universal \\ {\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ - uninstantiated universal\\ {\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ - thin particulars\\ {\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ - bare particulars};

        %\node[anchor=west] at (0,-1) {Legend:};
        %\node[anchor=west] at (0,-1.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ - instantiated universal};
        %\node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ - uninstantiated universal};
        %\node[anchor=west] at (0,-2.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ - thin particulars};
        %\node[anchor=west] at (0,-3) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ - bare particulars};
        \node[anchor=center,above = 0.1cm of B.north west,font=\bfseries\large] {Space-time manifold}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this be close to what you need? Use of `scope` environment wrapping your legend in side and apply `[shift={(xx,yy)}]` to suit your needs for the locations. Furthermore, for the title manifold, you can use `xshift=xx` to move it to the right.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/9,3.2/1/10,2/1.5/8,1.5/2/6, 2.5/2/7,1.2/2.5/2,2/2.5/4,3.1/2.5/5,2/3/1,2.9/2.9/3}{
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,label={[xshift=-3pt,yshift=2pt,scale=0.7]-60:$\mathrm{P}_{\z}$}] (\z) at (\x,\y){};
        }
        \node[draw,rectangle,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[draw,rectangle,top color=white,bottom color=gray!60,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (B) at (1.3,5) {};
        \draw (A.north west) -- (B.north west)
              (A.north east) -- (B.north east)
              (A.south west) -- (B.south west)
              (A.south east) -- (B.south east);
        \node (U) at (-1,5) {$\mathrm{U}_1$};
        \node at (-1,2) {$\mathrm{U}_2$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(6cm,5cm)}]
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend left] (1.west);
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend right] (2.south);
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-1) {Legend:};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-1.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ - instantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ - uninstantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-2.5) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ - thin particulars};
        \node[anchor=west] at (0,-3) {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ - bare particulars};
\end{scope}
        \node[anchor=center,above = 0.1cm of B.north west,font=\bfseries\large, xshift=1cm] {Space-time manifold}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use positioning library (which you already loaded).

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/9,3.2/1/10,2/1.5/8,1.5/2/6, 2.5/2/7,1.2/2.5/2,2/2.5/4,3.1/2.5/5,2/3/1,2.9/2.9/3}{
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,label={[xshift=-3pt,yshift=2pt,scale=0.7]-60:$\mathrm{P}_{\z}$}] (\z) at (\x,\y){};
        }
        \node[draw,rectangle,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[draw,rectangle,top color=white,bottom color=gray!60,anchor=south west,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=4cm] (B) at (1.3,5) {};
        \draw (A.north west) -- (B.north west)
              (A.north east) -- (B.north east)
              (A.south west) -- (B.south west)
              (A.south east) -- (B.south east);
        \node (U) at (-1,5) {$\mathrm{U}_1$};
        \node at (-1,2) {$\mathrm{U}_2$};
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend left] (1.west);
        \draw (U.east) edge[bend right] (2.south);
        \node[anchor=west,below right = 0cm and   1cm of B]  {Legend:};
        \node[anchor=west,below right = 0.5cm and   1.25cm of B]  {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ - instantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west,below right = 1cm and   1.25cm of B] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ - uninstantiated universal};
        \node[anchor=west,below right = 1.5cm and   1.25cm of B] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ - thin particulars};
        \node[anchor=west,below right = 2cm and   1.25cm of B] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ - bare particulars};
        \node[anchor=center,above = 0.1cm of B.north west,font=\bfseries\large] {Space-time manifold};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Adjus the values in `below right = 2cm and   1.25cm of B` suitably as you like. The first  value is below value and the second one is right value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a soltuion where the legend is positioned relative to the north west corner of the bounding box of the drawing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Create a scope which includes the drawing (figure) and the legend
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=figure_with_legend]
            \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/9, 3.2/1/10, 2/1.5/8, 1.5/2/6, 2.5/2/7, 1.2/2.5/2, 2/2.5/4, 3.1/2.5/5, 2/3/1, 2.9/2.9/3}{
                \node[circle,%
                    fill,%
                    inner sep=1.5pt,%
                    outer sep=0pt,%
                    label={[xshift=-3pt,%
                        yshift=2pt,%
                        scale=0.7]-60:$\mathrm{P}_{\z}$}] (\z) at (\x,\y){};
            }
            \node[draw,%
                rectangle,%
                anchor=south west,%
                minimum width=4cm,%
                minimum height=4cm] (A) at (0,0) {};
            \node[draw,%
            rectangle,%
            top color=white,%
            bottom color=gray!60,%
            anchor=south west,%
            minimum width=4cm,%
            minimum height=4cm] (B) at (1.3,5) {};
            \draw (A.north west) -- (B.north west)
                (A.north east) -- (B.north east)
                (A.south west) -- (B.south west)
                (A.south east) -- (B.south east);
            \node (U) at (-1,5) {$\mathrm{U}_1$};
            \node at (-1,2) {$\mathrm{U}_2$};
            \draw (U.east) edge[bend left] (1.west);
            \draw (U.east) edge[bend right] (2.south);

            % Place the legend relative of the north east corner of the drawing
            \node[anchor=north west,%
                align=left] (legend_title) at ($(current bounding box.north east) + (0.5, 0)$) {Legend:};
            \node[below=0.20 of legend_title,%
                anchor= west] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_1$ -- instantiated universal};
            \node[below=0.70 of legend_title,%
                anchor=west] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{U}_2$ -- uninstantiated universal};
            \node[below=1.20 of legend_title,%
                anchor=west] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_1 \ldots \mathrm{P}_2$ -- thin particulars};
            \node[below=1.70 of legend_title,%
                anchor=west] {{\tiny$\blacksquare$} $\mathrm{P}_3 \ldots \mathrm{P}_{10}$ -- bare particulars};
        \end{scope}

        % Place the title centered above the drawing and the legend
        \node[align=center,%
            anchor=center,%
            above=of figure_with_legend,%
            font=\bfseries\large] {Space-time manifold};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```